# Are we notified when someone does an edit to our answer? If not, what can be done to discover it?

Tags: discussion

[Is it appropriate to correct someone else's answer in an edit?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/is-it-appropriate-to-correct-someone-elses-answer-in-an-edit)

The above tackles the ethics of editing someone else's answer.

---

However, I currently have one user advising another to edit my answer as follows:

> you could also just edit this answer to add clarifications. The
>   original author will have chance to accept or reject the edits. That
>   is often better for future readers than adding a different-but-same
>   answer. – SRM 7 mins ago
>   [Does harmony have to be invented?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/131556/does-harmony-have-to-be-invented)

This is all very well but as far as I know, the system doesn't notify me if someone has added something to my answer.

**Question**

How do I know if someone edits one of my answers. Maybe even years later?

(a) Does the system actively notify me?

(b) If not, where do I look to find out generally? (Other than returning to every single one of my answers to check?)

Comment: AFAIK we only get notified if the editor doesn't have full edit rights (i.e.: reputation < 2000).

Comment: @chasly from UK Congrats on the 10K+, I'm curious about this too, the answer by kingledion is (slightly) inconsistent with my experience, that being said, it may have been a different site on the network - - . I'll look it up at some point (wade through many data points without the tools to filter them).+1

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does actively notify you in your inbox if your post has a suggested edit. I don't know if you can see this link, but [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/55128) is what I see when someone suggests an edit.

It does not notify you when someone with edit privileges edits your post. I demonstrated this by looking through my personal [inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/6545286/kingledion?tab=inbox) (I imagine you can't see this one) and seeing that there was no notification when Frostfyre edited [one of my questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/131423/revisions) yesterday.

You can see if you were notified of my edit to your post [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/131479/revisions), done just now.

Obviously, it is not right to change an author's post to conflict with their original intent, without notifying them. Hopefully, anyone with edit privileges will know this.

Comment: You do get notified, *but* there is a notion of a "significant" edit.  Edits that just change a few characters are treated as minor; the system assumes it's just typos, even though a few characters can change a lot if they're the right characters.  Also, title-only edits and I think tag-only edits don't notify.